# What is the best video software that can play more than one instance besides Gnome MPlayer?

Tags: gnome, video, mplayer

What is the best video software that can play more than one instance besides Gnome MPlayer?

I'm tired of using Gnome MPlayer that always creates a pop out dialog about “Failed to open VDPAU backend libvdpau_nvidia.so” everytime I play my videos with it.

Comment: You already asked this twice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I really like [SMplayer](http://packages.ubuntu.com/smplayer) IMO it's has a better and more intuitive interface to mplayer than Gnome-mplayer.

```
sudo apt-get install smplayer
```

Answer (score 10):

"The best" is subjective. I prefer [VLC Media Player](http://packages.ubuntu.com/vlc)

```
sudo apt-get install vlc
```

Comment: VLC has all the same features as MPlayer, but they're setup differently (for example, by default the playlist takes over the main window, but this can be changed to be it's own window).

Answer (score 1):

**SMPlayer**, very popular and a great front for mplayer allows multiple instances:

[image]

[image]

To **install SMPlayer**:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:rvm/smplayer
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install smplayer smtube
```

**VLC** has similar options:

[image]

[image]

[Install VLC](http://www.videolan.org/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can suppress the error messages by creating a little config file. Here's mine (sitting in `~/.mplayer/config`):

```
[default]
vo=vdpau,xv,
vc=ffh264vdpau,ffmpeg12vdpau,

ao=pulse
really-quiet="1"
fs=1
xineramascreen=1
msglevel=all=0
showsubtitles=0
```

Mine does extra things (like displaying it full-screen on the right-hand monitor in a TwinView setup, disabling subtitles by default and not spouting any error messages (the bit you want).

You could simply have:

```
[default]
really-quiet="1"
msglevel=all=0
```

Long live mplayer.

Comment: how to go over there?

Comment: What do you mean?